# Shell sort of integer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, shell, sorting

I am new to C and trying to learn shell sorting.I am trying to sort an integer array in ascending order.Here is my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 9, 7, 4, 8, 6, 7,2,1,6 };
    int n =10; //array length

    for (int c = (n / 2); c > 0; c = c / 2)
    {

        for (int i = c; c < n; i++)
        {
            int t = a[i];
            int j;
            for (j = i;( j >= c) && (t < a[j - c]); j = j - c)
            {
                a[j] = a[j - 1];

            }
            a[j] = t;

        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

On compiling this code in Visual Studio Express an error message comes asking either to close or debug and the output terminal not shows any output.I can't figure out what is wrong in this code.I would appreciate if someone could explain, and perhaps point me to a solution that would do what I want.

Comment: whats the exact error?

Comment: Perhaps `for (int i = c; c < n; i++)` should be `for (int i = c; i < n; i++)` ?

Comment: actually there is no error while compiling.As soon as the output terminal comes a message comes shellsort.exe (My project name) has stopped working with two options-Debug and Close program

Comment: Run it in a debugger. It'll pinpoint the exact line where the program is crashing, and will let you examine the variables etc.

Comment: Your code compiles? I thought VS didn't support C99!

Comment: Yes it compiles after changing some settings and thanks a lot your previous for loop change  solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right, just replace `for (int i = c; c < n; i++)` with `for (int i = c; i < n; i++)`
'c' will always be lesser than 'n' that's why your code is falling into infinite loop.

Comment: thanks it worked.Just one more change needed to be made at a[j] = a[j - 1] to a[j] = a[j - c];

Answer (score 0):

```
try to add this code....
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
 int arr[30];
 int i,j,k,tmp,num;
 printf("Enter total no. of elements : ");
 scanf("%d", &num);
 for(k=0; k<num; k++)
{
  printf("\nEnter %d number : ",k+1);
  scanf("%d",&arr[k]);
}
for(i=num/2; i>0; i=i/2)
{
 for(j=i; j<num; j++)
 {
   for(k=j-i; k>=0; k=k-i)
   {
    if(arr[k+i]>=arr[k])
        break;
    else
    {
        tmp=arr[k];
        arr[k]=arr[k+i];
        arr[k+i]=tmp;
    }
   }
  }
}
printf("\t**** Shell Sorting ****\n");
for(k=0; k<num; k++)
 printf("%d\t",arr[k]);
getch();
 return 0;
 }
```